# Genetic Algorithm in Optimization of Events

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, genetic-algorithm

I'm  a data analysis student and I'm starting to explore Genetic Algorithms at the moment. I'm trying to solve a problem with GA but I'm not sure about the formulation of the problem.

Basically I have a state of a variable being 0 or 1 (0 it's in the normal range of values, 1 is in a critical state). When the state is 1 I can apply 3 solutions (let's consider Solution A, B and C) and for each solution I know the time that the solution was applied and the time where the state of the variable goes to 0.

So I have for the problem a set of data that have a critical event at 1, the solution applied and the time interval (in minutes) from the critical event to the application of the solution, and the time interval (in minutes) from the application of the solution until the event goes to 0.

I want with a genetic algorithm to know which is the best solution for a critical event and the fastest one. And if it is possible to rank the solutions acquired so if in the future on solution can't be applied I can always apply the second best for example.

I'm thinking of developing the solution in Python since I'm new to GA.

Edit: Specifying the problem (responding to AMack)

Yes is more a less that but with some nuances. For example the function A can be more suitable to make the variable go to F but because exist other problems with the variable are applied more than one solution. So on the data that i receive for an event of V, sometimes can be applied 3 ou 4 functions but only 1 or 2 of them are specialized for the problem that i want to analyze. My objetive is to make a decision support on the solution to use when determined problem appear. But the optimal solution can be more that one because for some event function A acts very fast but in other case of the same event function A don't produce a fast response and function C is better in that case. So in the end i pretend a solution where is indicated what are the best solutions to the problem but not only the fastest because the fastest in the majority of the cases sometimes is not the fastest in the same issue but with a different background.

Comment: Great, have fun with that. So what is your question?

Comment: If the GA are a good way to resolve the problem, and if so what are the best tools to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure of what your question is, but here are the elements you need for any GA:

A population of initial "genomes"

A ranking function

Some form of mutation, crossing over within the genome

and reproduction.

If a critical event is always the same, your GA should work very well.  That being said, if you have a different critical event but the same genome you will run into trouble.  GA's evolve functions towards the best possible solution for A Set of conditions.  If you constantly run the GA so that it may adapt to each unique situation you will find a greater degree of adaptability, but have a speed issue.

You have a distinct advantage using python because string manipulation (what you'll probably use for the genome) is easy, however...
python is slow.
If the genome is short, the initial population is small, and there are very few generations this shouldn't be a problem. You lose possibly better solutions that way but it will be significantly faster.

have fun...

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the [GARAGe](http://garage.cse.msu.edu) Michigan State. They are a GA research group with a fair number of resources in terms of theory, papers, and software that should provide inspiration.

Comment: Thanks, i will search around on their material.

Answer (score 0):

To start, let's make sure I understand your problem.
You have a set of sample data, each element containing a time series of a binary variable (we'll call it V). When V is set to True, a function (A, B, or C) is applied which returns V to it's False state. You would like to apply a genetic algorithm to determine which function (or solution) will return V to False in the least amount of time.

If this is the case, I would stay away from GAs. GAs are typically used for some kind of function optimization / tuning. In general, the underlying assumption is that what you permute is under your control during the algorithm's application (i.e., you are modifying parameters used by the algorithm that are independent of the input data). In your case, my impression is that you just want to find out which of your (I assume) static functions perform best in a wide variety of cases. If you don't feel your current dataset provides a decent approximation of your true input distribution, you can always sample from it and permute the values to see what happens; however, this would not be a GA.

Having said all of this, I could be wrong. If anyone has used GAs in verification like this, please let me know. I'd certainly be interested in learning about it.

Comment: AMack i add more information in the topic. You understand the core of the problem but i specified some details.

Comment: So you are looking for some form of decision support system in which superior functions are suggested based on the current situation?

Comment: Yes, the diferent Solutions to the problem are given by the data and adequation to the problem, and new solutions and problems are included because there will be updates on the data.

Comment: Some like this:

If you have problem A the better solutions are the 1 and 4; if you cannot apply them solution 3 can work.

If you have problem B the better solution is 3. Solution 7 can be a good solution too.

So i need more than one solution and rank them.

Comment: Well, if you need to rank your components the problem is a bit more difficult. Most algorithms are designed to select a single choice given a set of inputs, not a sub-selection. I think what you want will depend heavily on the specifics of your problem. Also, most ML solutions require that you have a single quantitative measure of performance. You might be able to get around this by running several models optimized for different solutions and selecting from them, or simply finding a weighting you like.

Comment: My big concern would be that if you are creating new functions because the dataset changes significantly over time, you'll need to be careful to keep your model up to date.

Comment: For propuses of test in a initial phase i will only consider one data set without changes in the data. But with the ranking question it will be dificult to implement that with a GA?

Comment: This problem, as described, isn't really in the realm of what GAs are designed to do. You could perhaps use GAs to tune parameters in a separate function that selects the Solutions to apply, but at that point you're likely better of doing something else entirely. I'd recommend taking a look at other learning algorithms (e.g., Random Forest, ANN - maybe have a network that estimates the error associated with a function and use that to rank?).
The ranking will be as difficult as you want it to be. If you can boil your performance metric into a single value, then it *should* be straightforward